# Preserve Line Breaks From TextArea

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm using a textarea to enable users to input comments.  However, if the users enters new lines, the new lines don't appear when they are outputted.  Is there any way to make the line breaks stay.

Any idea how do preserve the line breaks?

Comment: I've just disabled htmlawed, and it seems that it has nothing to do with line breaks, the line breaks still don't show.  So I'm just writing the textarea data directly to mysql, and it doesn't show up when i echo data from mysql database.

Comment: I've also browsed the mysql table using phpmyadmin and seen the comment field.  No <br/> tags are being stored,

Comment: I'm doing a Facebook style comment system, so I don't really want it to be wysiwyg.  No ideas why line breaks don't preserve then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep textarea input format after using mysql\_real\_escape\_string to store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968206/keep-textarea-input-format-after-using-mysql-real-escape-string-to-store)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Two solutions for this:

1. PHP function [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

   **e.g.,**

   ```
   echo nl2br("This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r");

   // will output
   This<br />
   is<br />
   a<br />
   string<br />
   ```
2. Wrap the input in `<pre></pre>` tags.

   **See:** [W3C Wiki - HTML/Elements/pre](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre)

Comment: +1, Just awarded a privileged spot on my Favorites for PHP `nl2br()` :)

Comment: I think, choosing and styling <pre></pre> much much better for xss.

Answer (score 42):

Here is what I use

```
$textToOutput = nl2br(htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

`$text` is the text that needs to be displayed
`$textToOutput` is the returned text from `nl2br` and `htmlentities` so it can be safety displayed in the html context.
`ENT_QUOTES` will convert both double and single quotes, so you'll have no trouble with those.

Comment: I believe UTF-8 is now the default in PHP. But of course it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: How to possibly insert white spaces between texts?

Comment: You should always store data raw in the database. Then convert and sanitize the data before you display it.

Answer (score 3):

Got my own answer:  Using this function from the data from the textarea solves the problem:

```
function mynl2br($text) { 
   return strtr($text, array("\r\n" => '<br />', "\r" => '<br />', "\n" => '<br />')); 
}
```

More here: http://php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 1):

i am using this two method steps for preserve same text which is in *textarea* to store in mysql
and at a getting time i can also simply displaying plain text.....

**step 1:**

```
$status=$_POST['status'];<br/>
$textToStore = nl2br(htmlentities($status, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

In query enter `$textToStore`....

**step 2:**

> write code for select query...and direct echo values....

It works

Comment: You should always store data raw in the database. Then convert and sanitize the data before you display it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function getBreakText($t) {
    return strtr($t, array('\\r\\n' => '<br>', '\\r' => '<br>', '\\n' => '<br>'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function breakit($t) {
    return nl2br(htmlentities($t, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

this may help you

pass the textarea wal

Answer (score -8):

why make is sooooo hard people when it can be soooo easy  :)

```
//here is the pull from the form
$your_form_text = $_POST['your_form_text'];


//line 1 fixes the line breaks - line 2 the slashes
$your_form_text = nl2br($your_form_text);
$your_form_text = stripslashes($your_form_text);

//email away
$message = "Comments: $your_form_text";
mail("destination_email@whatever.com", "Website Form Submission", $message, $headers);
```

you will obviously need headers and likely have more fields, but this is your textarea take care of

Comment: This is insecure and not quite relevant to the question.

Comment: Just try it.... Post to email or SQL.... Potatoes potatoes..... Try running the lines and fix the issue.... Without a bunch if lines of messy code that sometimes works or doesn't.... :)

Comment: Out of all the answers, this one is least concise

Comment: it works for me, tq