# Converting \r\n to line breaks in a textarea (not using a <br> tag) in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have searched throughout this site and google, and could not find a viable solution. There are solutions, but none seem to work for me.

I have a text area that serves as the input for a form, as well as the output (editable) when displaying the form to edit. So, I have a textarea like so:

```
echo '<textarea>'.$resolution.'</textarea>';
```

If I enter something with line breaks, it is interpreted as \r\n wherever there is a carriage return. Example:

```
Input: 
    This is a

    test.

Output:
    This is a\\r\\n\\r\\ntest.
```

Now, I found it simple to remove the extra slash by using stripslashes as follows:

```
$resolution = stripslashes($resolution);
```

...but, now the output is:

```
This is a\r\n\r\ntest.
```

I cannot figure out how to convert \r\n to a line break (that is, without using a 
 tag, since that would only output <br> within the textarea, where html would not be supported. I've tried all of the following, but none of them worked:

```
//Effort 1
$resolution = trim($resolution);

//Effort 2
$resolution = nl2br($resolution);

//Effort 3
$resolution = htmlentities($resolution);

//Effort 4
$resolution = preg_replace("\\r\\n","<br>",$resolution);
```

I'm now at a complete loss. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it feels like this was answered over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011641/how-can-i-use-css-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-an-html-code-block -- basically: just let CSS deal with the newlines instead

Comment: try putting the `<textarea></textarea>` between `<pre>` tags. If you store your data in a database you might want to put the insert between `<pre>` tags aswell

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how then to remove the \r\n even if I could deal with it in CSS?

Comment: @SuperDJ If I had This is a<br>test. as my output, I could certainly try that. However, all I get is This is a\r\n\r\ntest. or (if using a couple of the efforts listed above, I get *nothing*

Comment: possible duplicate of [keep textarea input format after using mysql\_real\_escape\_string to store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968206/keep-textarea-input-format-after-using-mysql-real-escape-string-to-store)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has two different string building modes. The first uses single quotes, and will do absolutely no variable or special character substitutions. That's what you're using.

The second is variable-embedding in double quoted strings, which should work:

```
$text = str_replace("\\", "\", $text);
echo "<textarea>$text</textarea>";
```

The `\r` and `\n` should now be active carriage return and newline characters in your output, not the character "slash" and then an 'r' or 'n'

Answer (score 3):

Just use double quotes on str_replace

```
str_replace('\r',"\r",str_replace('\n',"\n",$resolution));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

or if you're really dealing with double backslashes:

```
str_replace('\\\\r',"\r",str_replace('\\\\n',"\n",$resolution));
```

Comment: Good answer, but use an array instead of two function calls. More efficient that way.