# Inserting line breaks in mysql from a form

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserve Line Breaks From TextArea When Writing To MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql)

I have created a form that is inserting data into mysql database but I would like the form to insert line breaks (when I press the return key) into the database from the form so I can have paragraphs when displaying the information from the database. At the moment information from the database is just displaying as all in one line despite pressing the return button on the form (text area) when entering the info.how can I do this? I am using php and am quet new so please help.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your current output look like? How exactly are you entering the data?

Comment: And btw for your info, if you don't understand from the possible duplicate, answer is use `nl2br()`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `<textarea>` div , then you will be able to capture the new lines, from there you can just get the input you need via normal `$_GET or $_POST`

What i am guessing is that you just echo the output from the database, use `<pre></pre>` for formatting your output or nl2br function of php.