# display the mysql result in same pattern as it saved

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a form containing text area. I am entering text in this manner -

```
  Hi Dear,

  How are you .

  Just reply when you get my message.
```

I am using mysql database, in that its storing the same manner. 
But when I am displaying it, its just displaying in single line.
like -

> Hi Dear, How are you . Just reply when you get my message.

But I don't want it like this, I want to display it in the same manner as it stored in the database.

If anyone know the solution of this reply me please.

Thank you

Comment: how are you retrieving it from the db?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Since you are displaying this in a text area, and this lines are stored as a single value in the db, then they should be ended by `<br />` like this:

```
  Hi Dear, <br />

  How are you .<br />

  Just reply when you get my message.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
\n\r   or   \n   or   \r
```

By:

```
<br />
```

PHP function:

[nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

## ELSE

```
$content = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $content);
```

Comment: it is nl2br() not ln2br().

Comment: Thank you very much, its working exactly what i want. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php function `nl2br($input)` on your text input before it goes into the database. It will replace line breaks with `<br />` tags.

Comment: i tried it, its working correctly. But this one - "$content = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $content);" is far better for me. Thank you to reply