# Textareas with paragraphs(next line) conflicting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have this jquery code

```
 setInterval(function() {
        if(yo.getTime() <= d5.getTime() && yo.getTime() <= d.getTime()){//compare yo time variable with current time variable(d) and also with the end time(so that the textboxes dont exceed the endtime)
            <%
             ResultSet rsta2=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_start where date='"+date+"' ");%> //A table which contains data typed in the textbox(In my case I have 12 data columns hence the counter,for 6 users).
             <%  while(rsta2.next()){%>
                var freq=$('#freq').val();//freq=30
                freq=parseInt(freq);
                //appending to the body of the html
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<pre><div><label style="float:left;">'+yo+'</label></div><textarea rows="15" cols="70" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox" ><%=rsta2.getString("data")%></textarea></pre><input type="hidden" name="timer' + counter + '" id="timer' + counter + '" value="'+msToTime(yo.getTime())+'"/>');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                yo.setMinutes(yo.getMinutes() + freq);
                counter++;
```

This code adds textareas after every half an hour.This part works.Next when I add text in the textarea for example 
[image]

Text without paragraph formatting(continuous text),this also works,i.e it gets retrieved back from the database to the textarea with no problem,and the textareas continue to appear after half an hour.
Problem arises now,check this image [image]

As you can see I have written in paragraphs form here,this goes into the database,but once it goes to the next line there is **no** space between the two words in the database,for example this line `ldhnjglfdhngfdhngjk  fdbnvjcxmbnjvm` gets saved in the database as `ldhnjglfdhngfdhngjkfdbnvjcxmbnjvm`(continuos string).But the main problem arises when retrieving it back on the textareas,the textareas dont appear at all.Nothing at all.Not a single textarea.What is creating a conflict?

**UPDATE**

I tried putting hello1,hello2,hello3 on 3 seperate lines on the textarea and I got this error [image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is causing this problem because there are dependencies that we cannot see. It may be a problem with your html generation, but that will be quite tricky to spot. However, some things that might be helpful:

1. Opening the dev tools in the browser (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> in chrome or firefox) do you see any errors when the text areas do not appear (e.g. internal server errors - 500)?
2. Opening the dev tools in the browser and going to the network tab, do you see the expected network data being returned to the browser when the text areas do not appear.
3. Is it possible to paste the network data into a jsfiddle (for example) and see if it renders correctly.
4. Can you compare the data in the database which causes it to fail with the data where it succeeds and determine the minimum case which causes the failure?
5. Anything else that you can do to reduce the problem space.

Comment: i have updated my question,I found an error after you telling what to do

Comment: from what I see the paragraphs(nextline) creating a problem

Comment: @user3040563 have you tried nl2br. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5049048/746754