# Html form PHPMailer keeping the message structure

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I have a website with a contact form that uses PHP mailer to send the e-mail. It works perfectly fine, but the only thing I kinda dislike is that it removes all the white lines and enters a user might use.

So, if the user submits this message:

> Hello,
>
> I have a question.
>
> Thanks

We will receive the above message like this:

> Hello, I have a question. Thanks

It uses the following code (Only showing the lines I think have anything to do with it, if you think I'm missing any lines that are importent for this please ask)

```
<form method="post" action="controleren.php">
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="70"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden">
```

Then in controleren.php it's the following code.

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;
```

I'd like the message to look the same as it was when the user submitted it. Is this possible?

Comment: "*Is this possible?*" Sure it is! What have you tried so far to try and solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Maybe what you need is here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql

Comment: did u used any function like **trim()** ,  **string_replace()** etc

Comment: you might be try [this link](http://in3.php.net/nl2br)

Comment: The function posted by the creater of that thread did it @singe31, thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it has helped you to find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change:

```
$mail->Body    = $message;
```

into

```
$mail->Body    = nl2br($message);
```

I assume you are sending your email in HTML format

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the whole issue altogether by not sending as HTML. A plain-text-only message will preserve layout - there's little point in having identical HTML and plain versions when one will do, plus it's faster and more efficient.

You can do it like this:

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Body = $message;
```

This does of course assume that there is nothing else in the message whose formatting you do want to preserve, but that wasn't in your question...