# Accept line break and special characters in a text area

Tags: php, html

This qeustion seems simple but i loss lot of my time playing with it.

My requirement is simple i want a text area that supports line break i.e if a user enters(line break) and again types some text.When this value is stored in database and if i want to display that text on some page than it should exactly display with same formatting as entered.

Also the text area should support some special characters like this text **mofrém**.Here these characters are displayed as boxes.

Using tinymce is an option i guess, but is there any simpler solution? Can these text be manipulated using php?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For line-break you can use: `echo nl2br("<td>" . $row['attrib1'] . "</td>")`. Something like that.

Comment: I would use TinyMCE myself just stripped down and setup for your usage. You can then process things when the text is submitted. Replace `\r\n` with another separator? Use `nl2br()`. It's not exactly clear from your description what you want to do with it. What have you tried?

Comment: @Twisty using nl2br() solves my first problem but how to handle the special characters as i have priovided with an example text.Do you have any idea on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a similar question that has been answered:

[Preserve Line Breaks From TextArea When Writing To MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql)

---

### Posted by user [Zuul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352449/zuul)

Two solutions for this:

1. PHP function [nl2br():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

**e.g.,**

```
echo nl2br("This\r\nis\n\ra\nstring\r");

// will output
This<br />
is<br />
a<br />
string<br />
```

2. Wrap the input in `<pre></pre>` tags.

**See:** [W3C Wiki - HTML/Elements/pre](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre)

Edit:

In reply to comment. To store/encode special characters use:

```
nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
```

Then to decode again special characters:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
```

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Thanks, but what about the next question about the special character.Do you have any idea about that?coz i need both the feature

Comment: @Sham White i have tried above method but no results.It again displays the boxes.in the place of special "é" character.Is this due to the absence of font or something?

Comment: @sham i figured out the issue with the special character. By the way  thanks for the help.