# How can I preserve the text paragraphs from a textarea input while sending in url with GET method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using GET to send text from textarea element. When I enter two or more paragraphs, the formatting is gone and paragraphs got merged as single paragraph.

Or suggest any other way to send larger texts (about 200 plus) words through request.

Comment: you are using ajax or form for sending data?

Comment: It is better to send large data through post, not get. Also, a GET request should never modify data. Only POST should modify data.

Comment: then appending it to the url

Comment: but on server end, both all text comes in single line. why? why not in blocks as i wrote.

Comment: yes @WisdmLabs, I am appending it to url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve Line Breaks From TextArea When Writing To MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$comments = stripslashes(trim($_GET['data']));, you can use $_POST as well

<textarea><?= nl2br($comments); ?></textarea>
```

you can use the same while storing  and use `nl2br()` while displaying.