# i am not able to insert text as pareagraphs in php mysql in a format through editor

Tags: php, html, mysql, editor

I am building a cms in php and inserting large content in database, for that i am using text editor. But when i give blank space inb front of paragraph or i write something on new line its not getting inserted in mysql table. I am giving muy code below...

```
<script>

        $(function() {

                    $("#btn-submit").click(function() {


                        var content =document.aboutform.descr.value = $('#editor').html();
                        var title=$("#title").val();
                        var id=$("#id").val();
                        //var active = $('input[name=make_active]:checked').val();

                        var dataString ='title1='+title+'&content1='+content+'&id1='+id;
                        //alert(id);
                        //alert(id);

                        //alert(firstname);
                        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                        //var dataString = 'title1=' + title + '&content1=' + content; 
                        //alert(dataString);

                            // AJAX code to submit form.

                        $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../admin/update_about.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(response) {


                                    $("#status").html(response);

                                                        },

                            });
                            //closes ajax call



            return false;


            });
            //closes button click
    });

    </script>   

And this is php code

$title = $_POST['title1'];
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content1']);
$id = $_POST['id1'];
$sql="UPDATE about_us SET title='".$title."',content='".$content."' WHERE about_id= ".$id;
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: do you mean the new line character or the space character is not being inserted ? or the whole text is not being inserted in database ?

Comment: yes...when i format the text like new line or when i add blank space somewhere then whole text not inserted

Comment: Does this solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql ?

Comment: no not yet...it doesnt allow to insert