# How to preserving line breaks in short description?

Tags: php, line-breaks

```
<div class="as space divider"></div>
<span class="as medium text"> <?php echo Validator::sanitize($this->row->body, "string", 300)?> 
</span>
<a href="#jump_desc">(read more)</a>
```

Hi, please help... I have a .php with this code, but line breaks they are not considered.

Who can please tell me how I can do?

Comment: Do you mean that the string in `$this->row->body` contains newlines that are not respected when seen in the HTML Page?

Comment: if it's a `\n` character, you could prolly try your luck using `nl2br()`

Comment: That's right, the text is duplicated without respecting line breaks that instead they are present in the long description text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a beginner and I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: `nr2br(Validator::sanitize($this->row->body, "string", 300))`

Comment: _“I'm a beginner and I don't really know how to do it”_ - that should not stop you from typing something like “php preserve line breaks” or similar into Google on your own though, right? And that would have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql and many others in no time.

Comment: Thank you for the advice you wanted to give me, please consider that I have already done on my own initiative what you have proposed, but I have not found an effective solution for the type of code I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

If your body contains newlines, you can do this:

```
<span class="as medium text">
    <?= nl2br(Validator::sanitize($this->row->body, "string", 300))?> 
</span>
```

The magic is "nl2br" which means "new line to break row".

Read more: [nl2br function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Thanks for replyr, this solution you have proposed seems not to be ideal, the <br> are not considered.

Comment: so your string consists of <br>? Then what happends if you use htmlentities instead of nl2br?

Comment: my string is a short description taken from row->body. Text content is entered in a text editor with <br>. Short version is shown with no  line breaks.  tried with this code but it doesn't solve the problem...
`<span class="as medium text">
    <?= nl2br(Validator::sanitize($this->row->body, "string", 300))?> 
</span>`

Comment: when you print it, you mean you see the <br> tag in site? I think its your validator::sanitize that escapes it from being intepreted as real html

Comment: @ PatricNox No, I dont see <br> tag in site, the new sentence that should be shown on a new line of text remains in the same line after  <br>. I don't know what to do to fix it.